# Vuejs / Laravel turns integer to string

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

So i have a website that is Laravel & Vue based, and works perfectly on my Homestead server, but for some reason on the live server there are a few issues.
The main issue seems to be that a few numbers on the live server are being represented as strings instead of integers.  The code otherwise is the exact same.  Thoughts as to why this might be?

Comment: did u find solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a prop without v-bind, it is always interpreted as a plain string (as all attributes are), no matter what its content is.

If you want to pass a literal number, you need use v-bind:

```
<!-- this passes "5" -->
<calc additions="5"></calc>

<!-- this passes 5 -->
<calc :additions="5"></calc>
```